# Have zoom work on x-axis, with y-axis to auto-scale to data points shown on visible graph segment

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have a graph plotting with ChartJS and plugin 'chart-plugin-zoom' for zooming. 
I need to auto-scale y-axis to data points shown on visible graph segment while zoom on x-axis.
How I can do it?

```
zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: chart.options['maxValue'] && chart.options['maxValue'] !== 0 ? 'xy' : 'x',
    rangeMin: {
      x: 60000, // Limit zoom in range: 1 min
      y: chart.options['series'][index] && chart.options['series'][index].beginAtZero ? 0 : null
    },
    rangeMax: {
      x: chart.options['maxX'] - chart.options['minX'],
      y: chart.options['maxValue'] && chart.options['maxValue'] !== 0 ? 1.2 * chart.options['maxValue'] : null,
    }
 }
```